# Why this assignable expression?

Tags: c++

New to c++, and I have this code I want to run but it's showing `expression is not assignable` i can put here a smaller piece of code that is similar to what I'm building,

```
int main(){
    complex<double> constant(0,0);

    real(constant)=1/3;

    cout << constant;



    return 0;
}
```

Now when you build it, it shows the expression mentioned above:

`WW.cpp:83:26: error: expression is not assignable real(constant) = 1`

Comment: What are you _trying_ to do?

Answer (score 4):

The **problem** is that the call expression `real(constant)` in your example, is an **rvalue** of type `double` and so cannot be used on the left hand side of an assignment.

If you want to set the real component then you can pass the value to the member function `real` as shown below:

```
//------------vv---->pass the value here
constant.real(15);
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ptTROmOsM)

Comment: that actually works in xcode, still it didn't work in visual studio.

Comment: @Marouane1994 It also works in gcc, clang and msvc, see [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/91f8jsv5G). If you have further problem with visual studio, then feel free to ask a separate follow up question and tagging `visual studio`.

Answer (score -5):

The value you want to assign to real(constant) is not possible due to this complex constant(0,0) you assigned the value here with the default value.

Comment: This is nonsensical answer. Please think before writing an answer.